# Colour Change during deselection of dates in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I change the colour during `selectoverlap` of dates in `fullcalendar`?.Now its always remaining as green colour. 
Following is my snippet,

```
     select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
      var startdate = start.format('Y-MM-DD');
      var enddate = end.format('Y-MM-DD');   
      dates.push(startdate + '' + '/' + enddate);
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },
     selectOverlap: function (event) {
     return !event.block;
     }
```

Comment: what element is it you want to change the colour of?

Comment: I want to change the background colour of the date during select overlap..

Comment: the background colour of the whole day on the calendar you mean? The "selectOverlap" function only gives you the data for the event that is being overlapped. Therefore there isn't enough info in the callback to know on which day the overlap is occurring (remember, events can go across multiple days). Also, on what event would you change the colour back again?